# How can I pass a Text string as a PHP Exec command

Tags: php, string, text, arguments, exec

I am trying to pass a Text string as a variable using the PHP Exec command line, but the entire text is not being passed.

The text is like this:

```
$title_page = 'Channel | This is the channels title';
```

then the exec line is:

```
exec("$path_to_php $emailer $article_sub_security_var $article_id > /dev/null &");
```

Im retrieving them like this:

```
$article_sub_security_var = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
$article_id = $_SERVER['argv'][2];
$page_title = $_SERVER['argv'][3];
```

The command line is working properly with the exception of $page_title.  It only returns part of the string and not all of it.

Any suggestions to pass it in full much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing `$title_page` or even `$page_title` anywhere in your exec statement :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The command line is working properly with the exception of $page_title. It only returns part of the string and not all of it.

I guess your problem is the `|` (pipe) in your page title, try using [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) on `$title_page` before.

Comment: Sorry.  The command does include $page_title in it.  My error.  darthmaim - could you show me what the code would look like on $page_title.  Would it go in the exec command line?  so something like this:  exec("$path_to_php $emailer $article_sub_security_var $article_id escapeshellcmd($page_title) > /dev/null &");

Comment: I just tried using  escapeshellcmd($page_title) but it doesnt work.  I tried removing the pipe, but it seems to only return the first word of the text string.  It seems to return any text upto the occurance of the first space.

Comment: you have to include `$page_title` in quotes (`"`), since it contains spaces, like so: `exec("$path_to_php $emailer $article_sub_security_var $article_id \"$page_title\" > /dev/null &");`

Comment: Thank you.  That works perfectly.  I had also just tried escapeshellarg which also worked.  Thankyou very much.